# Moving Magento 2 to local system

Tags: magento2, install

I have a Magento 2 website in our server. I want to setup a local copy of the website in my system. In Magento 1, we usually take a complete backup of the files and DB and place them in the target system. Then we would remove the app/etc/local.xml file which will proceed the installation again.

What is the equivalent for Magento 2 for the same process?

Answer (score 7):

Here is my sample bash script, which automatically updates Magento 2 development environment from a production server:

If you do it manually, you need do the following steps:

- Ajdust the database credentials in the `app/etc/env.php`file.
- Adjust the root URL (`web/unsecure/base_url` и `web/secure/base_url` options) in the database:

  `UPDATE core_config_data 
  SET value = 'http://example.ru/' 
  WHERE path IN ('web/secure/base_url', 'web/unsecure/base_url');`
- Adjust the URL for the `design/head/includes` option:

  `UPDATE core_config_data
  SET value = REPLACE(value, 'http://old.com/', 'http://new.com/')
  WHERE path = 'design/head/includes';`
- Delete the cache:

  `rm -rf var/cache`

Comment: I have done all this, and the homepage loads, but none of the other pages. I am running magento 2 with php7.0

Answer (score 1):

please check local.xml

for db user name and password is proper.

> open database and core_config_data table change old url to local url.

**I hope this will help you.**

Answer (score 1):

Migrate magento db and files to your local server and then edit following things:

1. In Magento 2, you need to edit the `app/etc/env.php` file with new configurations according to your local server.
2. Import db, goto `core_config_data` table change `base url / secure url` to your local `server url`.